# Microsoft.ReportViewer --> Ignore NULL Values

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, report-viewer2010

I have a List of Objects which I transfer to a ReportViewer. If the ReportViewer tries to access a NULL property of one object it doesn't work. Cause of the flexibility I want to add every object no matter if one property of the object is null or not. Is there any option on the side of the ReportViewer where I can say that null objects have to ignored?

I try this and it works but don't want to add at every property an if clause in the report
[Binding data on ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104285/binding-data-on-reportviewer)

regards Chris

Answer (score 0):

Can you loop through the objects before assigning the datasource and change the null values to empty strings (or the equivalent to your datatype)?